# What would be the correct GridbagLayout configuration to get such a display?

Tags: java, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Here is what I want to obtain:

[image: expected whole display]

The problem I'm faced with relates to this top right part:

[image: expected display]

With my code, the blue block is desperately not spanning under *both* green blocks. It is stuck either to the left or to the right (depending on the weights I apply, the gridx and gridy values staying the same):

[image: actual display] or [image: actual display]

I have correct gridx/gridy values, but I can not manage to get correct weights. What would be the correct code?

Edit : here is a minimal working example :

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.add(panel);

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JLabel score1 = new JLabel("Score1");
    JLabel score2 = new JLabel("Score2");
    JLabel team1 = new JLabel("Team1TestTest");
    JLabel team2 = new JLabel("Team2TestTest");
    JLabel clock = new JLabel("Clock");

    // Layout
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

    gbc.weighty = gbc.weightx = 1;

    // First two lines
    gbc.gridy=0;

    // -teams
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    panel.add(team1,gbc);
    gbc.gridx=2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    panel.add(team2,gbc);

    // -score 1
    gbc.gridy=1;
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    panel.add(score1,gbc);
    // -clock
    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    panel.add(clock,gbc);
    // -score 2
    gbc.gridx=3;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    panel.add(score2,gbc);

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

    while(true) {}
}
}
```

Result:

[image: actual MCVE result]

Comment: It would be good to have your actual code as a starting point.

Comment: for better help please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It's a MVE... it's not complete, there's missing components to be able to take it and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Edit: added a true MCVE

Answer (score 3):

You can create another `GridBagLayout` panel and add it in first panel as a left part of the second row with width equals 4.

[image]

Comment: I thought everything could be done in a single Layout. Too bad... And why 5 ?

Comment: My mistake. I ment 4 :) I had the same issue and solved it like this.

Comment: To get really nice fluid layouts in Swing I generally use lots and lots of jpanels for all things that are similar or need to act as one unit.